# How to perform a mail merge with word from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, mailmerge

When a button on a form is clicked I want text from text boxes to be used as the fields in a mail merge template. I have created a text file, and when the button on the form is clicked, I write the contents of the text boxes to the text file. I make sure the text file is in the correct format i.e. field headings at the top etc. I have created the corresponding mail merge template which is using the text file as the mailing list. My question is how do I initiate the mail merge with code in vb.net please?

Comment: This is unanswerable on this site. You need to research may be on codeproject.com. Try something, come here when something doesn't work. sorry

Comment: In which file format is your "mail merge template", is it a Word file? You could check out [this mail merging example](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Document/Examples/Mail-Merge-Word-Csharp-Vbnet/901).